# Resolve linux core dumped

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I created an application that receives commands from another process.
There the two exit commands.

**exit**: exits the main process (and his threads) and let the child processes finish their tasks.

**exit now**: exists the main process (and his threads) and sends a signal to exit the child processes to

The **exit** command is working fine but the **exit now** its not, I get a message saying "Exit (core dumped)" when I use it.

The exit command executes this function.

```
void processExit(){
    /* some code to close opened files and to wait for threads to finish (pthread_join) */
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The exit now command executes this function.

```
void processExitNow(){
    signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);
    kill(0, SIGQUIT);
    processExit();
}
```

So I think the **core dumped** is caused by the **kill** function. But why does this happen? I can´t find the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: The purpose of `SIGQUIT` is to generate a core dump. Use a different signal. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html

Comment: @DarkFalcon thanks it worked! Btw is there any way to send a signal to all child processes without sending it to the parent process?

Comment: @DanielOliveira Use the PID of the child. It's return by `fork()`. You can't with thread because it's the same processes. Don't call a thread a child process. It's a thread.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `SIGQUIT` is to generate a core dump. Use a different signal. [gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html)
                    – Dark Falcon